# How to integrate an existing application with Joomla?

Tags: php, codeigniter, joomla

I have built a web app for a client using the codeigniter framework. The client already has a basic website for his business built using Joomla.

Now that our web app is nearing completion our client wants us to somehow integrate the two so that movement between them seems seamless to the user. They don't want users hopping back and forth between sites. "The two should be under the same domain if possible", was asked of me at one point.

I'm unfamiliar with Joomla, however based on my research it looks like developing a component or using an Iframe is the best way to go about attempting this.

Are there any downfalls to this I should be aware of? Is this even feasible with Joomla. I've read where people have talked about doing this or similar things but have never seen a completed project. I've spent a lot of time the last couple days reading through forums and Joomla documentation and honestly feel like I've been running in circles on deciding how to do this.

Any recommendations or examples of how it could be done are appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: "Are there any downfalls to this I should be aware of?" - it will be slow, because you'll have to generate 2 pages: one using Joomla, and the 2-nd using CodeIgniter. Plus you'll need to install codeIgniter separately and have 2 copies of databases: for both CMSes. Messy thing.

Comment: @user4035 Yes, it does sound messy. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I would ask on the joomla SE site [joomla.se] .  But there are Joomla extensions that make it relatively seamless to go between it and other applications. People do it all the time.  You can also manage a single login if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating the CodeIgniter site into Joomla would be extremely difficult, if not impossible. "Messy" is too weak a word to describe the problem.

Moving between the two might be made relatively seamless by putting the CodeIgniter site in a subdomain of the Joomla site. Links on the Joomla pages would direct the browser to the subdomain and the other way around from CodeIgniter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I will go this route and recommenced it to the client.

Comment: Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Checking back in. That is what were are going with. Thanks again for the idea.